# What html tags are required to create a simple html email?

Tags: html, email

For a normal html page it's required or recommended to have html, head, meta tags, title tag, favicon, etc...

Whereas for an **html** email there's **no need** to have many of these tags. Then what's **required** for it so that it still remains valid as html document?

Is this valid html email?

```
<html>
  <head><!-- empty because nothing is needed here, but head itself is --> 
  </head>
  <body>
   content 123
  </body>
</html>
```

If not, give me an example of a minimalistic valid one.

Answer (score 3):

`<!DOCTYPE html>content 123` is sufficient for validity. There's no requirement for a title element in an HTML email if you provide a subject to your email.

The HTML standard specifically notes in the description of [the head element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-head-element):

> The title element is a required child in most situations, but when a
>   higher-level protocol provides title information, e.g. in the Subject
>   line of an e-mail when HTML is used as an e-mail authoring format, the
>   title element can be omitted.

The `html` `head` and `body` elements will be added automatically by the HTML parser, so their tags can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML specification does not special-case HTML that is used as the body of an email.

The Doctype is still mandatory. The title element is still mandatory. Valid HTML is valid HTML.

Comment: ok, but what is title in an email used for? where can I see it if not in the source code?

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that invalid HTML is actually more likely to be marked as spam by some software. So definitely go for validity!

Comment: @Rattiku — I would expect that very few, if any, email clients do anything with the title element. It is still required for the HTML to be valid.